# python comparing integers in conditions

Tags: python, integer, comparison

As a Java programmer I'm going to teach some kids Python. I tasked myself with creating a number guess game, to introduce after a few lessons.

```
from random import randrange

print("hi I've a number below 100 can you guess??");
theNumber = randrange(100)
theAnswer = raw_input("your first guess >")
while theNumber != theAnswer :
    print (str(theAnswer) + " .. " + str(theNumber) + str(theAnswer > theNumber))
    if theAnswer > theNumber:
        print ("you answer is too large")
    else :
        print ("you answer is too small")

    theAnswer = raw_input("your next guess >")

print ("You guessed!")
```

It looks like my number comparison goes wrong. Because after my first guess I see:

```
hi I've a number below 100 can you guess??
your first guess >50
50 .. 64True
you answer is too large
```

So in the example above 50 is greater than 64. I'm probably overlooking something terrible stupid, but at the moment I don't catch it.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with Python 3.x and teach that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fun program!  The problem was that `raw_input` captured the number as text, using `int` will convert it to a number:

```
from random import randrange

print("hi I've a number below 100 can you guess??");
theNumber = randrange(100)
theAnswer = int(raw_input("your first guess >"))
while theNumber != theAnswer :
    print (str(theAnswer) + " .. " + str(theNumber) + str(theAnswer > theNumber))
    if theAnswer > theNumber:
        print ("you answer is too large")
    else :
        print ("you answer is too small")

    theAnswer = int(raw_input("your next guess >"))

print ("You guessed!")
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason why Python 3 disallows comparisons between strings and numbers.

Comment: Python (2.7) Language Reference - [5.9 Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in)

Comment: Mark Ransom, would you recommend to teach Python 3? I'm worried about availability.

Comment: @drjerry Python 3 is an excellent teaching language, although it does have a few warts of its own. All versions of Python are freely available. Addon modules and online help are still probably more plentiful for Python 2.7 though.